# Where can I find html pages in a Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, web-development-server

I am currently learning Laravel. I had a pre-built script and I need to do some changes in it to make it usable... But as much I learnt from the web, I understood that the routes are specified in the Routes/web.php file.
But in the application I'm working on, the routes are defined in Routes/api.php file.

I even tried to find out the HTML pages in the Views folder but it only has the code for the tables which are there on the User Interface. All the controllers also return some data (like... return $data) in the end but no php or blade.php file is mentioned in any controller.

I need to find out the HTML pages so that I can change some components or elements from that website.

Please help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: The code was implemented only for `api` not implemented with view on the laravel, so, there will be frontend implementation calling the `api`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two possibilities:1- the application is only used for backend purposes, which is why the developer used API instead of routes.

or the application is made by laravel/vuejs. again laravel for backend and vue js for frontend.

in the second case try to search for .vue files

Comment: Yeah, there are .vue files in that application... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look for [blade templates](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade). You can find them in resources/views
directory, these files have .blade.php extension.

Comment: Thanks but I already mentioned that they only have tables structure and no other codes..!

Comment: Not an answer, based on the OP's comment on it.